# I can not display the default item in the select AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to do that when I set the board, list should be updated , if it is empty it will show n / a if it does not display the number `0` in the list. But I have a problem such that when I set an board which has 4 lists. Then I will set the list to the last position, for example `4` and then I will set an array that does not have lists. I have not set default n / a, only in the `drop-down list`.
I tried set `$scope.selectedList = '0'`; And it works in case of changing boards where there are lists but not where they are not.

Please Help. 
Here is the code:

**template in controller**

```
$scope.changeBoard = (_id) => {
  var params = {
    _id: _id
  };


  return ApiService.staff.selectedBoard(params).then((resp) => {
    if (resp.lists.length === 0 || !resp.lists) {
      $scope.downloadedLists.lists = [];
      $scope.selectedList = '0';
    } else {
      $scope.downloadedLists = resp;
      if (_id === $scope.board._id) {
        $scope.selectedList = $scope.mainList;
        $scope.selectedCard = $scope.mainCard;
      } else {
        $scope.selectedList = '0';
        $scope.selectedCard = '0';
      }
    }

  });
};
```

**template html**

```
<div class="transfer-btn">
  <span>Tablica</span>
  <span>{{board.name}}</span>
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedBoard" ng-change="changeBoard(selectedBoard)"> 
        <option ng-repeat="item in boards" value="{{item._id}}">
          {{item.name}}
        </option>   
      </select>
</div>

<div class="transfer-btn">
  <span>Lista{{selectedList}}</span>
  <span>{{board.name}}</span> {{selectedListIn}}
  <select class="form-control" name="" id="" ng-model="selectedList" ng-change=""> 
        <option ng-repeat="item in downloadedLists.lists" value="{{$index}}">
          {{item.list}}
        </option> 
        <option value="0" ng-show="downloadedLists.lists.length == 0">n/a</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Do you have some of test data ?

It should good for you to test and debug if you will have a test data like following example. The following example design the test data to 5 sizes starting from 0 to 4. After that you should trial and see the result one by one.

- What is the result when your input data is boardDataTest0 ?
- What is the result when your input data is boardDataTest1 ?
- What is the result when your input data is boardDataTest2 ?
- What is the result when your input data is boardDataTest3 ?
- What is the result when your input data is boardDataTest4 ?

Then it will help to give you some clue to test and debug in next step.

```
Test Data 0:
var boardDataTest0 = [];

Test Data 1:
var boardDataTest1 = [
  {"id":1, "name": "board1", "description": "bla..bla..bla1" }
];

Test Data 2:
var boardDataTest2 = [
  {"id":1, "name": "board1", "description": "bla..bla..bla1" },
  {"id":2, "name": "board2", "description": "bla..bla..bla2" }
];

Test Data 3:
var boardDataTest3 = [
  {"id":1, "name": "board1", "description": "bla..bla..bla1" },
  {"id":2, "name": "board2", "description": "bla..bla..bla2" },
  {"id":3, "name": "board3", "description": "bla..bla..bla3" }
];

Test Data 4:
var boardDataTest4 = [
  {"id":1, "name": "board1", "description": "bla..bla..bla1" },
  {"id":2, "name": "board2", "description": "bla..bla..bla2" },
  {"id":3, "name": "board3", "description": "bla..bla..bla3" },
  {"id":4, "name": "board4", "description": "bla..bla..bla4" }
];
```

Comment: Hey i know which is problem but i don't know how to fix it. Second select, he remember in which position is set. If i leave in position number 3, and later I will change board where is 3 items, is okay, he will not go to position 1 but he will stay still on position 3(where I want it on first position:D) if I will change board where is not 3 items for example 1 or 2 he will display empty select but in drop-down list is list but no have default value, look movie I make record https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4JBjJpIw4r8&feature=youtu.be

Comment: The movie is unavailable :)

Comment: uppp now you can watch :D